# awk print something if column is empty

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am trying out one script in which a file [ file.txt ] has so many columns like

```
abc|pqr|lmn|123
pqr|xzy|321|azy
lee|cha| |325
xyz| |abc|123
```

I would like to get the column list in bash script using awk command if column is empty it should print **blank** else print the **column value**

I have tried the below possibilities but it is not working

```
cat file.txt | awk -F "|" {'print $2'} | sed -e 's/^$/blank/' // Using awk and sed
cat file.txt | awk -F "|" '!$2 {print "blank"} '
cat file.txt | awk -F "|" '{if  ($2 =="" ) print "blank" } '
```

please let me know how can we do that using awk or any other bash tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is

```
awk -F '|' '{print match($2, /[^ ]/) ? $2 : "blank"}' file.txt
```

`match(str, regex)` returns the position in `str` of the first match of regex, or 0 if there is no match. So in this case, it will return a non-zero value if there is some non-blank character in field 2. Note that in awk, the index of the first character in a string is 1, not 0.

Here, I'm assuming that you're interested only in a single column.

If you wanted to be able to specify the replacement string from a bash variable, the best solution would be to pass the bash variable into the awk program using the `-v` switch:

```
awk -F '|' -v blank="$replacement" \
    '{print match($2, /[^ ]/) ? $2 : blank}' file.txt
```

This mechanism avoids problems with escaping metacharacters.

Comment: Hey , Can we use any variable instead of "blank" value like 

awk -F '|' '{print match($2, /[^ ]/) ? $2 : "$var"}' file.txt

Answer (score 6):

You can do it using this `sed` script:

```
sed -r 's/\| +\|/\|blank\|/g' File
abc|pqr|lmn|123
pqr|xzy|321|azy
lee|cha|blank|325
xyz|blank|abc|123
```

If you don't want the `|`:

```
sed -r 's/\| +\|/\|blank\|/g; s/\|/ /g' File
abc pqr lmn 123
pqr xzy 321 azy
lee cha blank 325
xyz blank abc 123
```

Else with `awk`:

```
awk '{gsub(/\| +\|/,"|blank|")}1' File
abc|pqr|lmn|123
pqr|xzy|321|azy
lee|cha|blank|325
xyz|blank|abc|123
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ /^ *$/) $i="blank"} 1' file
abc|pqr|lmn|123
pqr|xzy|321|azy
lee|cha|blank|325
xyz|blank|abc|123
```